# How do I allow multiple many-to-many entries in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5, many-to-many, relationship

In my Laravel5 app I have users, tasks, and user_tasks. A user can complete a task multiple times:

```
User:
  id
  name
  ...

Task:
  id
  name
  value
  ...

UserTask:
  id
  user_id
  task_id
  completed_on
```

If this were a normal many-to-many relationship I would have this function in the user class:

```
class User extends Model {
  // ...
  public function tasks(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'user_tasks', 'user_id', 'task_id');
  }
}
```

But I believe this means that user_id/task_id is a primary key on user_tasks. How do I change the relationships between Task and User if I want duplicate user_id/task_id entries in the join table?

Second question, what if I want a list of all unique tasks a user has completed, regardless of how many time a user has completed them?

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't trying to mean it would place a unique key on those columns. I meant that it seems like belongsToMany should be used in a situation where there is only one join between any pair of User and Task objects, so situations where user_id/task_id could be a unique key.

Comment: `UserTask.id` should be the primary key. The others should be indexed, but not unique.

Comment: `$this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'user_tasks', 'user_id', 'task_id')` does NOT define any composite primary key. If you don't define composite key explicitly, Laravel just use the id. So in your case you don't have to change the relationship.